# Using extreme value theorem, show that the function (1-t^2) has an optimum value in the interval (0,1)

Tags: calculus

Here's my understanding of the question

Extreme value theorem states that if a function is continuous in [a, b], it attains it's optimum value in the interval

Since 1-t^2 is a polynomial, it is continuous everywhere (and hence in (0, 1))

Thus, we prove that the function attains optimum value in (0,1)

Comment: That should work. I think the question just wants you to prove the continuity of that polynomial.

Comment: The extreme value theorem only tells you that that the function, when *restricted* to the *closed* interval $[0,1],$ attains an optimum value in $[0,1].$ A more convenient tool here is to examin the sign of the derivative.

Answer (score 1):

That function $t\mapsto1-t^2$ does not attain neither its maximum nor its minimum on $(0,1)$. The theorem talks about continuous functions on closed intervals, and closeness is crucial.

Comment: @AnneBauval can you explain exactly what you don’t agree with?

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It was me who downvoted. I had to edit your post to be authorized to upvote.